# Docker force-build parent image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm running a multi-service application with several images. The environment of each image is pretty much similar, so, in order to avoid code duplication, a "base" image is created/tagged with the required programs/configuration. Then, this "base" image is used as a parent image for the various "application" images. An (illustrative) example is given below:

**dockerfile_base**: which I build `with docker build -f dockerfile_base -t app_base:latest .`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y 
    build-essentials
```

**dockerfile_1**: which is built with `docker build -f dockerfile_1 -t app_1 .`

```
FROM app_base:latest
COPY . .
RUN make test
```

And finally an example **dockerfile_2** which describes a different service based again on "app_base" and is built with `docker build -f dockerfile_2 -t app_2 .`

```
FROM app_base:latest
COPY . .
RUN make deploy
```

Usually, the "base" image is built manually at first. Then, the "app" images are also manually built. Finally, the services (images app_1, app_2, etc.) are run using `docker run` for tests or `docker-compose` for demo deployment.

This creates an issue: When working on a new workspace (e.g. a newcomer's PC) where no docker images are yet created, or when something changes in the "dockerfile_base", running just the `docker build` command for the app images will result in error or incorrect images. So, the question is: is there a way in docker to define these chain-builds? I guess that's difficult for `docker build` command, but would it be possible with `docker-compose`?

Comment: with manual builds, the most practical solution would be to just wrap each build in a script file and run both the "app_base" image build and the "app_#" build each time. If there are any changes in the "app_base", they'll be picked up each time the script for any app_# is run, and will just use the cache for subsequent app_# builds. The question remains if it is possible with docker_compose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so this is what I came up with which essentially streamlines the whole multi-build multi-image process with just 2 commands. The docker-compose.yaml file was created like this:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  # dummy service used only for building the images
  dummy_app_base:
    image: app_base:latest
    build:
      dockerfile: "${PWD}/dockerfile_base"
      context: "${PWD}"
    command: [ "echo", "\"dummy_app_base:latest EXIT\"" ]

  app_1:
    image: app_1:latest
    build:
      dockerfile: "${PWD}/dockerfile_1"
      context: "${PWD}"

  app_2:
    image: app_2:latest
    build:
      dockerfile: "${PWD}/dockerfile_2"
      context: "${PWD}"
```

So, to build all the images, I simply run `docker-compose build`. The build command essentially builds and tags all  the images in the order they appear in the docker-compose.yaml file, so when building app_1 and app_2, the dependency app_base:latest is already built. Then, running everything with `docker-compose up`. Note: This WILL create a dangling container for dummy_app_base service, but overriding its command with an echo, it will simply exit immediately.

edit: even in one command: `docker-compose up --build`

Answer (score 0):

[Multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) were invented for problems like this. An example might be:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest as app_base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essentials 
    
FROM app_base as app_name
COPY . .
RUN make
```

Comment: While this approach addressed code duplication, you'll end up with just one big dockerfile (probably impractical). Also, an additional issue would be how to tag the intermediate images